# Code execution flow using Observables or callback functions when using Angular Interceptors

Tags: angular, callback, observable

I have a situation where I would like to get the device geo-location using a service in Angular 4.

```
export class GeoHttpService implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let position: object;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       (position) => {
         position = position;
         console.log("position :", position) // here i get the data.
       },
       (err) => {
         console.log("error : ", err);
       }
    );

// here i need to return an Observable with the position taken from the callback function
// if I do console.log(position) it will not give me the position data so I can't modify
// the request.

 return next.handle(req);
}
```

Which one is the best practice way to do this in order to get position data and modify the actual request ? Right now the callback function is stopping me of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main approach here is:

1. wrap geolocation request in some promisify converters function to get promise from it.
2. Convert Promise to Observable
3. Merge next.handle(req) and resulted observable like it is described in this article https://medium.com/@danielcrisp/async-http-interceptors-with-angular-4-3-9e6e795da562

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thanks a million.